# Выть на Луну или Выть на луну?

Tags: прописная-строчная

В словаре Ожегова и Шведовой в качестве примера в статье *выть* приводится вариант со строчной. Неужели связь с астрономическим объектом в этой фразе потеряна?

Comment: Просто собаки малообразованы и не знают, что Луна — астрономический объект.

Answer (score 4):

Вопрос об *астрономичности* представления луны в обыденных выражениях интересен.  Но ведь и Солнце мы со строчной пишем, когда имеются в виду рядовые, привычные, чисто *визуальные* события - восходы и закаты солнца. Мы не вспоминаем гелиоцентрическую систему и не говорим что-то вроде : "Земля совершила поворот вокруг своей оси и подставила Солнцу свое восточное полушарие..."  Допустим, волки с собаками образумятся (пройдут соответствующий курс наук) и начнут выть именно на Луну... тогда людям придется ходить по Земле?  Ногами - по Земле!

Answer (score 4):

Словарь Лопатина "Прописная или строчная?" различает терминологическое (астрономический термин) и нетерминологическое значение слов "луна, земля, солне". Но трудности все равно возникают. Особенно много их связано с землей. Ведь это планета, на которой мы живем. Она и часть космоса, и близкий нам мир.

Например, население земли - это население планеты Земля (взгляд из космоса) и население земного шара (взгляд отсюда). Но, поскольку взгляд из космоса возможен только для инопланетян, побеждает значение "земной шар" и "земля" пишется со строчной.

Соответственно, можно предложить такой обиходный критерий различения: если подразумевается взгляд на объект из космоса (рассматриваем Луну по отношению к Солнечной системе или планете Земля как ее спутник), то пишем с прописной, а если подразумевается взгляд с земли и соотнесения с астрономическими телами нет - то со строчной.

Answer (score 3):

В качестве астрономического объекта Луна используется в следующих примерах:

Ты либо живешь на Луне, либо только что оттуда…
Что вода? Субстанция, послушная ветрам и Луне.
Великий итальянец  открыл на Луне горы и даже горные цепи.
В сентябре 1610 года он обнаружил, что Венера, подобно Луне, меняет вид от узкого серпа до полного диска.

В остальных случаях луна, когда луна не имеет значения небесного тела, а воспринимаетсяся только как видимый светящийся объект на небе, она пишется со строчной буквы, например:

Большая полная луна, словно скатившаяся с роскошного шпиля здания, беспомощно висела поодаль.

Также: Блестит луна, недвижно море спит. Ничто не вечно под луной.